# PHP Edit first line of a text file

Tags: php

I'm trying to edit the first line of a text file via PHP. I have broken my script down and tested the functions 1 by 1. My deletion of line 1 works fine. However I then attempt to insert a line at the beginning and it wipes the file to zero and then writes it.

My code:

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['jobname'];
$sunits = $_GET['s'];
$wunits = $_GET['w'];
$funits = $_GET['f'];
$vunits = $_GET['v'];
$tunits = $_GET['t'];
$data =  "S: $sunits - W: $wunits - F: $funits - V: $vunits - T: $tunits";

$f = "$filename.txt";

// read into array
$arr = file($f);

// remove second line
unset($arr[0]);

// reindex array
$arr = array_values($arr);

// write back to file
file_put_contents($f,implode($arr));

$handle = fopen("$filename.txt", 'r+') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$filename);
fwrite($handle, $data . "\n");
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would only use `file_get_contents() [file() in your case] + file_put_contents()`.
No need to use fopen() after (it is called when you call `file_put_contents()` actually.

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['jobname'];
$sunits = $_GET['s'];
$wunits = $_GET['w'];
$funits = $_GET['f'];
$vunits = $_GET['v'];
$tunits = $_GET['t'];
$data =  "S: $sunits - W: $wunits - F: $funits - V: $vunits - T: $tunits";

$f = "$filename.txt";

// read into array
$arr = file($f);

// edit first line
$arr[0] = $data;

// write back to file
file_put_contents($f, implode($arr));
?>
```

you might need to use `implode(PHP_EOL,$arr)` so each element of the array is on it's own line

Comment: Seen your solution after I wrote my own :)

Comment: That $arr = file($f); line doesn't work for me. Var_dump shows bool(false).

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a line at the beginning of a textfile, just at the end. What you have to do is add the new line to the beginning of the array and then write the whole array back:

```
// Read the file

$fileContents = file('myfile.txt');

// Remove first line

array_shift($fileContents);

// Add the new line to the beginning

array_unshift($fileContents, $data);

// Write the file back

$newContent = implode("\n", $fileContents);

$fp = fopen('myfile.txt', "w+");   // w+ means create new or replace the old file-content
fputs($fp, $newContent);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I've taken a spin of what you have suggested and simplified it.

Comment: Actually, Mash's solution down there is more elegant... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from your use of [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), which either creates a file if it doesn't exists or wipes the file clean then write contents. In your case you need to use [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) in append mode, [fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to write the data, then [fclose](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) to close the file. There will probably be another step or two in the exact code, but that is the general idea of append data to a file that already exists with content.

Comment: The first part of my code is working fine. It is deleting the first line perfectly fine. My issues starts when I fopen and insert the line. That is the point where everything gets wiped. For the purpose of this script, the file already exists and contains data. I am deleting the first line and replacing it with another.

Comment: Simplest bet is to just read the file, append the data to that read, and then rewrite the whole file. Not the best but will work fine depending on file type, contents, and size

Comment: That is pretty much what I have done. They are only small text files so no issues should arise.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end was rather than `unset $arry[0]` I set `$arr[0] = $data . "\n"` and then put back to the file and it is working. Anyone see any problems doing it like this?

Answer (score 0):

I researched this all night.  This was the best solution I could find. Fast, and low resources.  Currently, this script will echo the contents.  But you could always save to a file.  Thought I'd share.

```
        $fh = fopen($local_file, 'rb');
        echo "add\tfirst\tline\n";  // add your new first line.
        fgets($fh); // moves the file pointer to the next line.
        echo stream_get_contents($fh); // flushes the remaining file.
        fclose($fh);
```